# How to highlight the last occurrence of a string in a text widget?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I would like to highlight the last occurence of a pattern in a text widget (in Tkinter).

Example:

```
pattern = 'ssi'
string = 'ssiljkssilkjssi'
```

I want the last “ssi” to be in red and the rest of the text to stay in black. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe find the _first_ occurrence of 'iss' in 'issjklisskjliss'?

Comment: No, this is the last one.

Comment: Ok, guess I need to be a bit more explicit - reverse your source string and your pattern string, find the first occurrence of your reversed pattern in your reversed source, then reverse the source again, along with some simple arithmetic to correct the indices...

Comment: Ah ok sorry, i read too fast.
What do you mean by 'along with some simple arithmetic to correct the indices'?

Comment: Well, if you find the first occurrence of the reversed pattern at offset 5, then when you reverse the source string again, you don't want to look at offset 5, you want to look at `strlen(source)-strlen(pattern)-5`...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind